# Peewee: reducing where conditionals break after a certain length

Tags: python, peewee

This is what I have:

```
SomeTable.select.where(reduce(operator.or_, (SomeTable.stuff == entry for entry in big_list)))
```

The problem arises when I have a relatively large list of elements in big_list and I get this:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Is there another way to approach this that doesn't involve splitting up the list into several chunks?

Tried the suggestion to use any, here's my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/f9xk3li/Documents/GitHub/leoshop_web/leoshop_web/data_models/data_model.py", line 347, in <module>
    search_bins_all("BoA 0")
  File "C:/Users/f9xk3li/Documents/GitHub/leoshop_web/leoshop_web/data_models/data_model.py", line 179, in search_bins_all
    for d in generator.order_by(SomeTable.RetrievedDate.desc()):
  File "C:\Users\f9xk3li\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 282, in inner
    clone = self.clone()  # Assumes object implements `clone`.
  File "C:\Users\f9xk3li\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2202, in clone
    return self._clone_attributes(query)
  File "C:\Users\f9xk3li\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2412, in _clone_attributes
    query = super(SelectQuery, self)._clone_attributes(query)
  File "C:\Users\f9xk3li\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\peewee.py", line 2206, in _clone_attributes
    query._where = self._where.clone()
AttributeError: 'bool' object has no attribute 'clone'
```

And here's the code

```
generator = SomeTable.select()
generator = generator.where(any(SomeTable.BIN == entry for entry in big_list))
for d in generator:
    ....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `...where(SomeTable.BIN.in_(big_list))`

PeeWee has restrictions as to what can be used in their `where` clause in order to work with the library.

http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#query-operators

Comment: Oh god, why did I even write such a complication solution for something that simple... I don't remember ever seeing .in_ in the docs t.t

Comment: I did run into a "too many variables" error, but that's a sqlite limitation, that being said, this is working great!

Comment: If you can get `big_list` to be replaced with a PeeWee query, then I believe it'll do the lookup completely in the database, which might take care of the "too many variables" error.
I've only glanced through PeeWee docs for the first time today, and I'm not familiar with the sqlite error, but if it's what I think it is, then I'm pretty sure this will help you out.

Comment: Hmm.. a query in a query. Do you have any insight on how to do this? Because my long list actually comes from the database.

Comment: Assuming you used code similar to `SomeOtherTable.select()...` to create `big_list`, you'd simply put that line of code into the `in_()` method.

This is my first day looking at PeeWee stuff, so no gaurantees :)

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Jacob's comment on the approved answer, I think he's saying you can use subqueries rather than resolving all the IDs.

E.G.

```
admin_users = User.select().where(User.is_admin == True)
admin_messages = Message.select().where(Message.user.in_(admin_users))
```

Comment: This is freaking awesome. If I knew of this feature a while, that would've been great.

Comment: Peewee rocks, what can I say? ;)

Comment: Question though, say that in my user table I have countries, and I want to only get the countries, would I do: countries = User.select(User.country) and then do Message.select().where(Message.country.in_(countries))?